# Autolayout constraints with dynamic-sized cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I need to create a tableView with dynamic-sized cells. For this, I am using

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

in my viewController. Also I created a custom class for my cell.

Actually, it works, I have dynamic cell heights, but I want to have several subviews in my cell. For example, I need to add background view here.

```
class myCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
...
self.backView = UIView()
self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.contentView.addSubview(self.backView)

//1st constraint
NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0).active = true
//2nd constraint
NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0).active = true
```

The thing is, it doesn't work.
If I'm using both constraints, my cell heights are not longer dynamic, they all have the same height.

If I'm using just one of this constraints, cell heights are ok, but I'm getting this error:

> Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

In both cases my view (self.backView) is not visible.

Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: At least part of the problem is you're using UITableViewAutomaticDimension incorrectly.  You want to assign that to the tableview properties, NOT use it in the delegate methods.  That's why it thinks the heights are zero...

Comment: set UITableViewAutomaticDimension in viewdidload and have a try.